Account Record Type is reverting to old value when a new value is selected
I added 4 new account record type and assigned them to a new page layout. I assigned the new record types to my profile.
When I try to update an account record type, I can select the new record type and click save. However the account record type remains unchanged and no error messages are showing.
There are no active triggers or workflows.
What else could I try?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392579&type=1
